# posting JSON response status to server

Tags: javascript, json

I have this ajax function in my client-side script:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url : '/some_url',
  data:{number:5},
  success:function(data){alert("done");},
  error:function(xhr,textStatus,error)
  {
    console.log(xhr.statustext);
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Now, I want this JSON data to be rendered by my serverside logic in the following format (some emerging standard of JSON response):

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    /* Application-specific data would go here. */
  },
  "message": null /* Or optional success message */
}
```

for a successful message and

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "data": null, /* or optional error payload */
  "message": "Error xyz has occurred"
}
```

for a failed one. 
I have the status and error information in my client side JS script. How do I pass these to my serverside? Do I have to bundle them with the data I'm POSTing? Please point me in the right direction. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: A bit confused,  do you mean how to send the status, message and data back to client side? usually server is the one that is giving a response??  If from server side, usually status = HTTP status code, 200 = OK, 404 = Not found, 500 Internal error, etc. you can add message to it as well. Should be standard w/ whatever backend platform you are using.  as for data, it's part of the response body.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Why do you want to send the status back? The server should know itself the status and any errors when it does it work. Are you just trying to log server errors?

Comment: the "pass these to my serverside" portion is confusing me. can you kindly explain that? if the server is processing the request it should automatically know if went as expected or not (which will be server side logic).
If you want to make another call to send the resultant data somewhere, you can make another json in the __.always__ callback using the result and proceed accordingly. details on the callback here: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/

Comment: As I understand you, you have a template for your server responses on client side and want the server to use that? Is that right?

Comment: My server should render the received response in the format that conforms to what I have mentioned above. So I guess that's where these statuses should go in. Second, I dont want to log  them. The rendering json will be parsed by a few serverside functions.

Comment: Yes @Markai. Exactly. To be more precise, I have a JSON renderer in my server side to be rendered in the client side. It should return the json data in this format `{data:,status:,message:}` and likewise. If the status is FAIL, I can just return the message passed instead of having to handle failed requests at the client side, and sending alerts.

Comment: @suvartheec : Kindly read the previous response for Markai. By passing to serverside, I mean, the server logic can handle errors, but I need the exact client side message which can either be a 404 message or some custom message to be rendered along with it.

Comment: That's a bit redundant since response already have some of these things built in, but sure, you can wrap the status. message and data however you want and pass it to response body.  REST wise, might not be a good idea, are you always going to return 200 OK even on failure then?

Comment: If its a 404 NF no. Else, my custom message should be returned. If this is not a good idea can you please give me a clue on how to conform to the JSON response standards? At the server side?

Comment: if thats the case then its a server side issue and would depend on the server side technology used. if you are using REST in Java for example, you can return status code 200 with an object containing these data (which should be converted to json using json libraries)

Comment: I use Python-Pyramid in the server side. and I use request.POST.get to get my POST'ed parameters.

Comment: you can tag the question accordingly with the modifications that came out from these comments to attract the right people.

Comment: also you can use the deferred.always() callback as i mentioned which will be executed irrespective of the result of the http call (success or failure)

Comment: This seems to be a bit chatty back and forward kind of thing... request to server -> response from server -> response back to server (some kind of ACK / for logging?).  Honestly, I haven't seen the need to do something like this in any of the projects I've been involved in.  Usually things stop at where response is given back from the server.  I guess in scenario where client is acting as a worker, this might be useful? ie. query if any work available, server response w/ a task, client run task and post back task result to the server for collection.

Comment: Why are you sending the error message from the client to the server, have it bundled with other data and send it back? The `message` property is intended to bring server-side errors to the front-end. Errors thrown in the front-end can be brought to the user without any such detour.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use some kind of promise chain to send the message back to the server.

like:

```
getServerTask()
  .then(processTask)
  .then(sendTaskResultToServer)
```

in `sendTaskResultToServer` function wrap your message and task status in the JSON schema you mentioned and post it back to server.